# WIX: Uninstallation of product throws the error when file location("C:\Program Files\Product\Setup") of product is opened

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

Let's say I have opened the product installed location on file explorer, for example, "C:\Program Files\Product\Setup". Then when I go to Add or Remove program and uninstall the product, the uninstallation completes successfully. But the file explorer throws the following error:

`C:\Program Files\Product is unavailable. if the location is on this pc, make sure the device or device is connected..........`

I am hoping the file explorer to go back to the "C:\Program Files" path without throwing this error during uninstallation. I can't find any documentation related to this, any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

Comment: This is an error in File Explorer, not in the MSI, uninstall or WiX

Comment: Yes, I agree. I tried other software uninstallation and usually if the installation location is opened during uninstallation, instead of throwing an error the file explorer roll back to C:\Program Files. Not sure how that magic happens.